# Joint density of $(V,Z)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The joint density of $(X,Y)$ is $f_{XY}(x,y)=k(1-\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}),0<x<1,0<y<x$.

- Find the value of $k$ and say if $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not.

$\rightarrow k=6 \Rightarrow f_{XY}(x,y)=6(1-\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}})$; $f_X(x)=2x$ and $f_Y(y)=6(1+y-2^{\frac{1}{2}})$, so $f_X(x)f_Y(y)\neq f_{XY}(x,y)\Rightarrow X,Y$ are not independent

- Let $V=X$ and $Z=\sqrt{\frac{Y}{X}}$. Say if $V$ and $Z$ are independent or not.

$\rightarrow cov(V,Z)=\mathbb{E}(VZ)-\mathbb{E}(V)\mathbb{E}(Z)=\mathbb{E}(X^{\frac{1}{2}}Y^{\frac{1}{2}})-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(X^{-\frac{1}{2}}Y^{\frac{1}{2}})=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}=0 \Rightarrow V \perp Z$

- Find the joint density of $(V,Z)$.

---

Well, I'm having a bit of a problem with this: indeed I know that if $X \perp Y \Rightarrow f_{VZ}(v,z)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)|\det(J)|$, but in this case $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. So I thought I'd do in this way:

1. $F_{V,Z}(v,z)=\mathbb{P}(V\geq v,Z\geq z)=\mathbb{P}(X\geq x, \sqrt{\frac{Y}{X}\geq z})$ $=\mathbb{P}(X\geq x,X>\frac{y}{z^2})=\mathbb{P}(\frac{y}{z^2}<X<x)$;
2. $f_{X|Y}(x|y):=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}-y^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+y-2y^{\frac{1}{2}})}$;
3. $\mathbb{P}(\frac{y}{z^2}<X<x|Y=y)=\int_{\frac{y}{z^2}}^{x}f_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$ and then $\mathbb{P}(\frac{y}{z^2}<X<x)=\int_{\frac{y}{z^2}}^{x}\mathbb{P}(\frac{y}{z^2}<X<x|Y=y)f_X(x)dx$

Is it correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to say that V and Z are independent or not, you cannot use the covariance. That is, if two variables are independent their covariance is 0. This does however not work the other way around: if two variables have correlation 0, this does not imply that they are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say if $X,Y$ are independent or not no calculation is needed. In fact, Necessary Condition for independence is that the joint domain is rectangular....you have a triangle so they are NOT independent

To calculate the joint density of $(Z,V)$ let's use the Fundamental Transformation Theorem, setting

$$
\begin{cases}
v=x \\
z=\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}
\end{cases}$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x=v \\
y=z^2v
\end{cases}$$

The jacobian is $|J|=2zv$

So the joint density is

$$f_{ZV}(z,v)=12(1-z)zv\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(z)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(v)$$

It is very simple to see that

$$f_{ZV}(z,v)=6z(1-z)\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(z)\times 2v\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(v)=f_V(v)f_Z(z)$$

Thus the rv's V and Z are independent.

**IMPORTANT OBSERVATION**

The calculation of the covariance $Cov(Z,V)$ is not requested and finding $Cov(Z,V)=0$ says nothing about independence.

**Further explanation**

Fact: $X$ and $Y$ are not independent as their join domain is a triangle:

$$\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(x)\mathbb{1}_{(0;x)}(y)$$

using the above system

$$
\begin{cases}
x=v \\
y=z^2v
\end{cases}$$

we calculate the jacobian

$$
   |J|= \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}  \\
     \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}  \\
    \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    z^2&2zv  \\
    \end{bmatrix}=2zv
$$

Now simply changing the variables (this is called Fundamental Transformation theorem but it is just a variables' change) you get

$$f_{ZV}(z,v)=f_{XY}(z,v)\times |J|=6(1-z)\times 2zv=12zv(1-z)$$

When I look at this density, defined on the unit square $[0;1]\times[0;1]$ it is immediately to identify that

$f_{ZV}=f_Z\times f_V=6z(1-z)\times 2v$

If this is an issue for you, no problem at all! integrate with respect to z to derive $f_V$ and viceversa:

$f_V=\int_0^1 f_{ZV}(z,v)dz=2v$

$f_Z=\int_0^1 f_{ZV}(z,v)dv=6z(1-z)$

**Further question in same exercise**

It is also requested to calculate $\mathbb{P}[V^2+Z^2>\frac{1}{2}]$

Rmemebering that $z^2+v^2=\frac{1}{2}$ is a circumference with center in the origin and radius $r=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ we get

$$\mathbb{P}[V^2+Z^2<\frac{1}{2}]=\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}6z(1-z)dz\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-z^2}}2v dv\approx 0.234$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[V^2+Z^2>\frac{1}{2}]\approx 0.760$$

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Could you please copy below a link of the Theorem?

Comment: @FrancescoTotti : http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/4_4.html

Comment: No way. Reading the text I could say that if $X\perp Y$ we would have $f_{VZ}(v,z)=f_X(v)f_Y(z^2v)2zv$, but in this case $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. So I don't understand how you say that $f_Z(z)=6z(1-z)$.

Comment: @FrancescoTotti : ok, I will edit the answer with more details but it is very very simple. X and Y are not independent but it is not an issue. You do have their joint density so you use this denisity for your calculations. I immediately see that $f_{ZV}=f_Z f_V$ but if you do not see  that fact you can derive the two marginals. Ciao

Comment: @FrancescoTotti :edited....let me know if now it is clear...

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clear. So we can say that if $X\perp Y \Rightarrow f_{VZ}(v,z)=f_X(v)f_Y(z)|J|$, while if $X,Y$ not independent $\Rightarrow f_{VZ}(v,z)=f_{XY}(v,z)|J|$?

Comment: @FrancescoTotti : YES, CORRECT! Pheraps this book is better for you http://unina.stidue.net/Complementi%20di%20Analisi%20Matematica/Materiale/Gelli%20-%20Probabilita_parte2.pdf.  Read Paraghrap 6.7.2; Trasformazione $2 \rightarrow 2$. This books divides by the jacobian instead of multiply as I did but it is the same, for a "local inversion theorem"

Comment: For completeness, the last question of the exercise is to calculate $\mathbb{P}(V^2+Z^2>\frac{1}{2})$. Thus $\mathbb{P}(V^2+Z^2>\frac{1}{2})=\frac{4}{5}$. Thanks again!

Comment: @FrancescoTotti : sorry but I do not match with your result. I showed my caclulation in the further edit to my answer

Answer (score 0):

your integral doesn't integrate correctly the purple surface.

this is the drawing

[image]

For polar coordinates I apply them only when the integrand function is nice for a circle...I do not think this is the case, but anyway you can try